# Fail to deploy in heroku when using carrier wave and S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I am a newbie in rails.

Right now using a tutorial for ruby and rails. In one of the section we using carrier wave and AWS S3 for photo storage.

when i deploy in heroku, there is an errors like this :

"ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key"

i write on the carrir_wave.rb as follow:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      # Configuration for Amazon S3
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['******************'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['*************************']
      }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['*******************']
  end
end
```

when I am running my test in terminal, all test was good.

I had been setting the credential on heroku through:

```
$ heroku config:set S3_ACCESS_KEY=<access key>
$ heroku config:set S3_SECRET_KEY=<secret key>
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET=<bucket name>
```

I am really appreciate with any one help.

Answer (score 0):

Create some carrierwave.rb filr in config/initializers folder and place following code snippet in carrierwave.rb file

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                          # required
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],       # required
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']    # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  =  ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']                # required
end
```

and place your values for following keys in some .env file in project folder 
1) AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
2) AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
3) S3_BUCKET_NAME

Then re-run your server from terminal